# jQuery Mobile and Phonegap page change events issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm working on a mobile app that uses Phoengap, jQuery Mobile and the new Facebook plugin for Phonegap https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect.

First page is statis content and a button to connect with Facebook:

```html
<a data-role="button" data-theme="b" href="#home-page" data-icon="facebook" id="fb_connect">
    Connect with Facebook
</a>
```

I'm only offering support for touch devices, so the code is triggered on tap:

```js
        $('#fb_connect').live('tap',function(event) {
            FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
               console.log('login(): Logged in');
           } else {
               console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
           }
         }, {scope: 'email, user_likes, user_status, friends_status, user_checkins, friends_checkins'});

            $.mobile.changePage($('#map-page'), {transition: 'slideright', showLoadMsg: 'true'});

            return false;
        });
```

After the page changes, I want to populate the page with a Google Map which displays pins of nearby Facebook places. I want to do this dynamically so I need to use a page event and call the function responsible with this as soon as the page loads. The only event that gave any results was JQM's 'pageshow' event, but that only triggers after I interact with the page in some way (for example click).

Everything else works as expected. Any idea on what event I should be using? Also, when the map page loads, before tapping, I can still see the "Login with Facebook" text from the button, but nothing else on the page. Since I'm using the Apache Cordova Facebook plugin, I can't really test this in the browser, so I can't use Firebug or Chrome inspect...

Thanks, any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `pageinit` instead of `pageshow` if you need something earlier.

Answer (score 0):

`"pagecreate"` event executes before initializing the page, so I think it should work.